LSTM produces a straight line for predictionsout of range data
I have this problem:
I am trying to predict daily temperatures. I have data of 30 years, and I am using this neural network:
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=128,activation="relu", input_shape=(30, 1), 
return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=128, 
activation="relu",return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(64, activation="relu")))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=lr),metrics=['mse', 'mae', 'mape'])

I am using sliding windows to create a matrix to feed my LSTM
step=30
batch_size=16
epochs=500

The model adapts perfectly to train and data set. But when I make it predict data out of this sets, only a straight line is produced:
def autoregressive_prediction(model, initial_sequence, 
future_steps):
    predictions = []
    input_seq = initial_sequence

    for _ in range(future_steps):
        pred = model.predict(input_seq[np.newaxis, :, :])  
        predictions.append(pred[0, 0])  
        input_seq = np.roll(input_seq, -1, axis=0)  
        input_seq[-1] = pred[0]  

return np.array(predictions)

num_predictions = 500 

future_predictions = predict_future(model_LSTM_optimo, test, step, 
num_predictions)

future_predictions = future_predictions.reshape(-1,1)

if predicted.ndim == 1:
 predicted = predicted.reshape(-1, 1)

full_predictions = np.concatenate((predicted, future_predictions))

extended_index = np.arange(len(predicted) + len(future_predictions))

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.title("Temperatura máxima en La Paz - Vino Tinto (°C)", fontsize=18)
plt.plot(index, df_limpio['Temperatura Máxima'], c='blue')
plt.plot(extended_index, full_predictions, c='orange', alpha=0.75)
plt.legend(['Datos Reales', 'Predicción'], fontsize=15)
plt.axvline(x=tp, c="r")
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
plt.ylim(-0.1, 1.5)
plt.show()


I have tried modifying steps, epochs, adding layers, teacher_forcing_data and little change was made:

Blue graph are real data, yellow one predicted one. Straight line in the red rectangle predictions made for data out of dataset
